# The file is currently checked out or locked for editing by another user in document library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

I logged into a document library in my  SP 2013 site collection and checked out a file and started modifying the document.
At the same time another  user logged in and trying to check out the same file, It shows me "The file is currently checked out or locked for editing by another user" in SP 2013.
Wanted to know,how to get the display name/ login name of the another user?
This feature is available in previous version but does not exist in SP 2013.
How can I get the name of the another user ? Or is this a  default behavior of 
SP 2013 ?

Answer (score 3):

You can check that in library setting under "Manage files which have no checked in version"